# How to add user assigned identity to AAD group with Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I am able to add service principals and individual users to Azure Active Directory group with command:

`Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId GROUPID -MemberObjectId MEMBERID`

I'm giving the user assigned managed identity principal id from the portal as MemberObjectId. I suppose the ID is something else, but what it is and how to get it? I have tried client id as well, with no luck.

When I try to run the same command with user assigned managed id, it fails with the error:

`Line | 143 |              Az.MSGraph.internal\New-AzADGroupGraphRefMember @PSBoundP … |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | Resource 'XXXXX-...' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects | are not present.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I have one *User Assigned Managed Identity* named **`UserassignedMI`** like below:

[image]

To add the above identity to Azure AD group, I ran the same command as you by giving `Client ID` and got **same error** as below:

```
Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId <GroupID> -MemberObjectId <Client ID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

But when I used **Object (principal) ID** for `-MemberObjectID`, it worked and gave results successfully like below:

```
Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId <GroupID> -MemberObjectId <Object (principal) ID>
Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId <GroupID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **managed identity** added to the group successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for verifying this. I just realized that my problem is due to the fact that the managed identity was in subscription that was linked with Lighthouse, so even I can "see" it, I can query and find this managed identity, it actually doesn't show up on the portal if I try to add it in Azure AD. If I create a managed identity in the same main subscription, it works as you described above.